# Check if Array as Any exist element in Swift

Tags: swift

With an Array as Any object:

```
var a : [Any] = []
 let x : String = "This is X"
 let y : Int = 9
 let z : [Any] = ["1", "no. 2"]

 a.append(x)
 a.append(y)
 a.append(z)

let ele1 = 9
let ele2 = "This is test string"
```

Very simple if the a is String/Int array, but this is Any array!
How to check ele1, ele2 exists or not in a?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `Any` does not conform to `Equatable`, `[Any]` does not have a `contains(_:)` method. You cannot use `==` to compare `Any`s either.

However, `[Any]` does have a `contains(where:)` method that accepts a predicate. You can pass in a `(Any) -> Bool` and if there is anything in the array that makes the closure return true, `contains` returns true.

We can use `contains(where:)` to do exactly what you want. For example, if you want to check for ele2:

```
a.contains(where: { ($0 as? String) == ele2 })
```

What I did is that I casted the element to string first, then use `==`.

You can also create an extension that does this:

```
extension Array where Element == Any {
    func contains<T: Equatable>(_ element: T) -> Bool {
        return contains(where: { ($0 as? T) == element })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try something like this:

```
a.forEach({
    if let testInt: Int  = $0 as? Int, ele1 == testInt {
        print("found")
    }
})
```

And similar for any other types. I'm away from my computer so haven't tested the above, but I think it should work.